# Permanent Deleting of files still doesn't work for me (make_unused_managed_files_temporary = true)

Tags: 8, files

`make_unused_managed_files_temporary` didn't work for me.

I am using Drupal backend for the REST API frontend application.

Thats how the File input looks (because I am not sure if that setting is for that File elements, but guess so).

[image: How file field looks]

I read some informations about permanent files deleting, because I would like to delete files permanent from the file system and also database.

I was set the `make_unused_managed_files_temporary` to `true` and debuging, this is really true in the code.

I also found the configuration in `Backend / File system` - Delete temporary files after (6 hours), so this is on.

I am checking also the database `file_managed` before and after (and after 6 hours) file deletion for the flags like `status` that indicates `isTemporary()` method. But after uploading file, saving... then editing, and removing file, the file is still in the database as a status 1.

I am also checking DB table `file_usage` where there is still the item with `count=1` too, that should be not true (because of deletion).

And files maybe should move to /tmp folder, but that doesnt.
I am working on Drupal 8.5.6 and 8.7.2 on production, but the behaviour is the same.
I am doing something wrong? Is there some cron to be configured? Or another futher settings?

Edit 1: I think it is not a Media, but simply file widget - `/core/module/file`

Edit 2: The main problem is that, when I delete file, it stay in the database as a permanent flag (`status=1`), and also it has a count of usage 1 (`file_usage=1`). When I manually update database to set `status=0` and `count=0`, the cron works OK. Why the file usage and count stay on?

Comment: Can it be that cron actually dumps the garbage collection in the end and you have no cron set up?

Comment: Found the comment "apparently existed Permanent file with already 0 usage won't be changed to Temporary. That files need manually removed" and a link to https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2821423 on https://www.drupal.org/node/2891902

Comment: Okay, so how do you remove it then? What code? Can you add that to your question? Sounds you should maybe delete them properly calling some CRUD function and not simply remove them?!

Comment: IIRC unused files will be deleted after multiple cron runs. Wait for few crons to run ?

Comment: Thanks for your answers mates, but I have a new result, see the Edit 2.

Comment: Maybe Drupal has some Trash modul to confirm by default? Without extension

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just made a solution that works for me even the Drupal or config doesn't works properly. In my plugin I hooked up the `hook_cron()` for logging these unused files to proceed them next.

- SQL SELECT; query to fetch all `file_managed` `fid`'s. You can select only `status=1`, as permanent files, but I got all,
- PHP loop all id's and making a `Drupal\file\FileInterface` entity reference `$file = File::load($item->fid)` to check all the file references `$references = file_get_file_references($file)`. When the `$references` is `empty()` this file is unused. Save all that `fid` id's into array `$fids`,
- SQL UPDATE; build update query to null these rows: `UPDATE file_managed SET status=0 WHERE fid IN($fids)` and `UPDATE file_usage SET count=0 WHERE fid IN ($fids)`.

Finaly after next cron run the default `function file_cron() {...` will properly delete these files.